# DEFER not actually deferring

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Originally, I put all of my javascript in the head, but then I noticed that the page load time was very slow - not surprising. So, I moved all of my scripts to the bottom to eliminate the DOM render blocking effects.

On Google's PageInsights page, they say that's no longer the best practice and they recommend putting the scripts in the head and adding async loading

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

The problem I ran into with that and from my understanding is if you use async, then the script will execute as soon as it completes loading, so you can run into dependency issues - which is precisely what happened with jQuery and scripts that depended on it.

https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/

I found out that there's the defer attribute which is like async but it postpones execution until loading. If that's the case, why am I still hitting these dependency errors?

It doesn't happen every time. It just so happens that sometimes the script(s) that depend on jQuery load quicker than jQuery itself, as shown below.

My question is, what should I do to make sure that everything loads asynchronously but doesn't execute until the completion of loading?

Hopefully, this is a simple fix without a ton of fancy javascript.

[image: Console 1] 
[image: Console 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that asynchronous scripts are not guaranteed to execute in specified order and should not use document.write. Scripts that depend on execution order or need to access or modify the DOM or CSSOM of the page may need to be rewritten to account for these constraints.

Simple suggestion: just place your scripts at the bottom, or only use the async tag unless they have no dependencies whatsoever.

Anything that depends on Jquery has a dependency on Jquery being executed (loaded) first.

Also best practice might be chunking a bundle file, micro-organizing the loading sequence, and using a CDN with a cache buster as needed (if you're not using versioning), but that sounds like over-optimization at this point.

Alternatively, if I'm looking at your code right, you need a defer on the `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js` script line.

Comment: Defer downloads in async but executes in order, unless the src attribute is missing on the script tag.
[MDN][1]

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

You are still downloading your jquery script with async, change it to also be defer.

*Some extra detail on async and defer that you might already know:*

async: downloads your script while browser is rendering, then stops the rendering once download of that one script is finished and executes it, then continues rendering.

defer: downloads your script while the browser is rendering, then wait till the DOM is finished rendering before executing your scripts in the correct order (ONLY if the also have a src attribute).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

"**defer**
This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

To achieve a similar effect for dynamically inserted scripts use async=false instead. Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document."